# google adwords api php library

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

I have setup the account with my mcc account and executed the examples reporting code for campaign performance report for one of my customerclient id.

This is the code:

```
<?php

// Include the initialization file
require_once __DIR__ . '/examples/AdWords/Auth/init.php';
require_once __DIR__. '/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Util/v201601/ReportUtils.php';


function DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwqlExample(AdWordsUser $user, $filePath,
    $reportFormat) {
  // Optional: Set clientCustomerId to get reports of your child accounts
   $user->SetClientCustomerId('731-721-7585');

  // Prepare a date range for the last week. Instead you can use 'LAST_7_DAYS'.
  // $dateRange = 'ALL_TIME';

  // Create report query.
  $reportQuery = 'SELECT CampaignName, Impressions, Clicks, Ctr, AverageCpc, '
      . 'Cost, Date,Conversions,ConversionRate, CostPerConversion,CampaignStatus FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT '
      . 'WHERE  CampaignStatus = ENABLED DURING THIS_MONTH';

  // Set additional options.
  $options = array('version' => 'v201601');


  // Download report.
  $reportUtils = new ReportUtils();
  $reportUtils->DownloadReportWithAwql($reportQuery, $filePath, $user,
      $reportFormat, $options);

  printf("Report was downloaded to '%s'.\n", $filePath);
}




try {

  // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
  // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.
  $user = new AdWordsUser();

  // Log every SOAP XML request and response.
  $user->LogAll();

  // Download the report to a file in the same directory as the example.
  $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/report.csv';
  $reportFormat = 'CSV';

  // Run the example.
  DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwqlExample($user, $filePath, $reportFormat);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  printf("An error has occurred: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
}

// Don't run the example if the file is being included.
if (__FILE__ != realpath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
  return;
}
```

I have executed this code and got the csv report where i have two fields AverageCpc, and Cost.

Both of these parameters must be rounded of or should be return in the same format as we see in the google adwords campaigns dashboard.

Here is the screenshot of how it looks i my csv file

```
Avg.Cpc | Cost
9788919 | 362190000
```

But when i validated with the adwords campaigns, it shows.

```
Avg.Cpc | Cost
9.7    | 36.21
```

Is there any problem with the code or i need to specify some extra parameters for AvgCpc Value and Cost to format it properly ???

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to divide the cost and the average cpc with 1000000, So you will get your format before you may process the  data further.